# App doesn't work in release version

Tags: c#, xamarin, httpclient, release

I'm creating an app using xamarin Cross Platform. Everything is working in debug, but when i bulid app in release version, app crashes. Application output:

```
 ERROR:
 [mono] Unhandled Exception: [mono] System.MissingMethodException:
 Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync'. 
 [mono]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[<LoadData>d__0] (POSSector.Mobile.<LoadData>d__0& stateMachine) 
 [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  
 [mono]   at POSSector.Mobile.LoginViewModel.LoadData ()
 [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  
 [mono]   at POSSector.Mobile.LoginCommand+<Bind>d__3.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  
 [mono] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- [mono]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
 [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  [mono]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () 
 [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  [mono]   at POSSector.Mobile.LoginCommand+<Execute>d__0.MoveNext () 
 [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  
 [mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync'.
```

Comment: are you running on a different machine that doesn't have the same version of .net / xamarin installed?

Comment: Check the assemblies. Specially System.Net.Http.dll. What is the assembly version?

Comment: In Options - Anroid Build- Linker / I set Don link and my App work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Options - Android Build- Linker / I set Don link and my App work ! 
[Info for problem](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/)

Comment: Mark your answer as correct answer, if you believe you find the answer.